# problem on My own implemntation of strlcpy?

Tags: c, string, strlcpy

Hello i just faced a problem when testing an implementation of `strlcpy`

```
long unsigned int ft_strlcpy(char *dst, const char *src, unsigned int len)
{
  unsigned int l;
  unsigned int i;
  i = 0;
  while (i < len - 1)
  {
      if (*src != '\0')
          *dst++ = *src++;
      i++;
  }
  *dst = '\0';
  return i + 1;
}
```

i did a test with the original strlcpy but i didn't get the same result
src = "string", len = 6
output of my strlcpy

```
return value = 6
dst = strin
```

output of the original strlcpy

```
return value = 10
dst = strin
```

the result is the same in dst but in the return value should be the length of the string trying to make

Comment: Why is it called `strlcpy` if it's supposed to be `strlcat`?

Comment: So are you talking about `strlcpy` or `strlcat` here? The `10` value suggests `strlcat` but the example you give suggests `strlcpy`.

Comment: Tip: `size_t` makes more sense than `unsigned int` or `long unsigned int`

Comment: yup i'm talking about `strlcpy` it's supposed to give the same output as mine but i don't know why its gives an output like `strlcat`

Comment: The return value of the `strlXXX` functions is supposed to be the total size that the result would be if you didn't hit the `len` limit. You're returning the limited length.

Comment: in the arguments i i'm giving it (`len` limit) to the original strlcpy

Comment: If you're saying Barnar is wrong, please provide a minimal, runable demonstration of the problem as required.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the correction i didn't realise that i did that lol

Comment: `ft_strlcpy(" ", "string", 6)` i did the same for the original strlcpy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strlcpy)

> The `strlcpy()` and `strlcat()` functions return the total length of the string they tried to create. For `strlcpy()` that means the length of `src`.

You're returning the length of the resulting string, not the length it would have been without the `len` limit.

Save `strlen(src)` in a variable and return that at the end.

```
size_t ft_strlcpy(char *dst, const char *src, size_t len)
{
  size_t l = strlen(src);
  size_t i = 0;

  while (i < len - 1 && *src != '\0')
  {
      *dst++ = *src++;
      i++;
  }
  *dst = '\0';
  return l;
}
```

Also, the `len` parameter and the return type should be `size_t`.

Answer (score -1):

It should return the length of the string to copy, not the length of the result.

---

You seem to be claiming you did

```c
ft_strlcpy(dst, "string", 6);  // 6
```

and

```c
strlcpy(dst, "string", 6);  // 10
```

But the output suggests you did something closer to

```c
ft_strlcpy(dst, "abcdefghij", 6);  // 6
```

and

```c
strlcpy(dst, "abcdefghij", 6);  // 10
```

`strlcpy` returns the length of the string it *tried* to create, meaning the length of the string that would have been copied if the limit hadn't been imposed. This is not what `ft_strlcpy` returns.

---

Fixed:

```c
size_t ft_strlcpy(char *dst, const char *src, size_t len) {
  if ( !len )
     return strlen(dst);

  size_t i = 0;
  while ( --len ) {
     if ( !( *dst++ = *src++ ) )
        return i;

     ++i;
  }

  while (*str) {
     ++str;
     ++i;
  }

  return i;
}
```

Comment: yes that's what i faced i don't know why `strlcpy` gives me a different result.